# Angular 10 - disable scrolling on parent while child is present

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

**Hi!**

I'm still learning Angular and i faced i problem while coding my app.

**PROBLEM**

I have a parent component, containing list of items, which im calling from backend.
I managed to create event that gets the data of each item on click to send this data to child component. There I display it in form of card:
(simplified code here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/card-scroll-wkck6p?embed=1 )

Problem I'm facing relates to mobile views, since these screens are smaller and they can't contain all the info in one view, but I'm unable to scroll the card. Scrolling moves parent only - just like in linked expamle.

**TODO**

The goal is to disallow parent scrolling, and make a child scrollable if it's height > screen height.
How can I make my parent component ***'overflow: hidden'*** or something like that while child component is present?

Comment: Enclose your child div in a container div and give it max height and overflow css in that way if children are present and are big in number then the container div will try to expand and hence your css will handle the scroll.

Answer (score 0):

> The goal is to disallow parent scrolling, and make a child scrollable if it's height > screen height. How can I make my parent component 'overflow: hidden' or something like that while child component is present?

Make sure scroll does not happen from `html` or `body`

styles.css

```
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Make sure both parent and child have separate scroll bars within them.
We enclose parent in a container of a fixed height and allow it to scroll within its container making sure child is outside that container.

html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="parent">
        ...
    </div>
</div>

<app-child (hideChildEvent)="hideChild($event)" *ngIf="showCard"></app-child>
```

css

```
.container {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 100%;
}
```

This is how a modal works

Again to make child scrollable, fix the height of the container of child content and allow scroll.

child css

```
.mask {
    ...
    height: 100%;
    overflow: overlay;
}
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/card-scroll-ywqb3f?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)